# Confusing result while converting degree into radian in C

Tags: c, double

```
  int x;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  x=(double)((x*3.14)/180);
  printf("%.6lf",x);
```

When I  run the above code and input x=60, I get -0.000000.

```
  int x;
  double a;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  a=(x*3.14)/180;
  printf("%.6lf",a);
```

But when I  run this above code, I get the correct answer.

I want to know where I am doing wrong. Is there problem in my type casting or use of double or any other thing? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

N.B. : I need to print output upto 6 digits after decimal.

Comment: `x` is an `int`. You can't make it a `double` at your will.

Comment: Unlike other languages (e.g. python), C does not change the type of a variable to match the value. Instead it changes the type of the value to match the variable. Since `x` is declared as an `int`, any value assigned to `x` will be converted to an `int`.

Comment: `3.14`?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Bathsheba...its pi im using

Comment: You're typecasting into double but `x` is still int and when you print with `lf` it expects a double but it is still an integer. Compile with the `-Wall` flag next time to gain better insight.

Comment: You're not using `pi`. You're using `3.14`.

Comment: @Pratik..  Can you provide any insight of how using a -Wall flag?

Comment: @NehalSamee. `gcc -Wall program.c` will show some insightful warnings you may have not noticed. 
Also following @Bathsheba suggestion, if you want to use pi, include `math.h` and use `M_PI` instead.

Comment: @PratikSampat: Except that `M_PI` is not required by the standard, so your code would not be portable. Oh joy!

Comment: @Bathsheba, or you could just `# define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846` which is what's in the `math.h` source?

Comment: @PratikSampat: See one of my better answers, written on the C++ tag, but the sentiment applies to C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778240/does-c11-14-17-or-20-introduce-a-standard-constant-for-pi/49778493#49778493

Comment: Ah neat! I've learned something new today. Thanks @Bathsheba!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

```
x = (double)((x*3.14)/180);
```

`(x*3.14)/180` is already a `double` therefore this line is equivalent to:

```
x = (x*3.14)/180;
```

but anyway the type of `x` remains `int`, so if `x` was e.g `300`, the new values of `x` will be `300 * 3.14/180 = 5.2333` which will be trunacated to `5`.

The second problem is here:

```
printf("%.6lf",x);
```

As explained before, the type of `x` is `int`, but the `"%.6lf"` format specifier requires a `double`. If the variable types don't match the format specifier, the behaviour is undefined.

The second version of your code is perfectly correct, but be aware that the user can only enter integer values.

BTW: 3.14 is a very poor approximation of PI, I'm sure you can do better.

Comment: Is my second  code correct??And should I use 22/7  or 3.1416 instead?