# How do I get C to differentiate between single and double floats when evaluating trig functions?

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm very new to C programming. I have to print the values of tan(0) to tan(pi/2) in steps of pi/20 for both single and double precision floats. However, when I use different data types to store the floats, nothing changes between single and double, and I expected the number of digits to change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415926

int main()
{
    float angle = 0.0;
    float pi_single = 3.1415926;
    printf("single precision:\n");
    while(angle < pi_single/2){
            float(tanangle) = 0.0;
        tanangle = tan(angle);
        printf("tan(%f) = %f\n", angle, tanangle);
        angle = angle + pi_single/20;
    }

    double angle2 = 0.0;
    double pi_double = 3.141592653589793;
    printf("double precision:\n");
    while(angle2 < pi_double/2 ){
            double(tanangle2) = 0.0;
        tanangle2 = tan(angle2);
        printf("tan(%lf) = %lf\n", angle2, tanangle2);
        angle2 = angle2 + pi_double/20;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to replicate the result of this Python program:

```
import numpy as np
theta_32 = np.arange(0, np.pi/2+np.pi/20, np.pi/20, dtype = 'float32')
print('single precision')
for theta in theta_32:
    print(theta)
    print(np.tan(theta))
print()

[enter image description here][1]
theta_64 = np.arange(0, np.pi/2+np.pi/20, np.pi/20, dtype = 'float64')
print('double precision')
for theta_new in theta_64:
    print(theta_new)
    print(np.tan(theta_new))
```

Comment: `float(tanangle) = 0.0;` is a very weird way to define `tanangle`. Most people write `float tanangle = 0.0;`, and writing it with parentheses will confuse people. Why did you write it that way?

Comment: Right, sorry. I'm not used to declaring variables, that's probably a leftover habit from Python.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `tanf` if you want the computation to take place in `float` rather than `double`.

Note also that when working with floating point, it's best to use an integral type, `int i`, say to count from 0 to 19, then use `pi * i / 20` for the angle. For further reading see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Wikipedia gives the format specifier for single precision floats as %f and double precision floats as %lf. Long double is %Lf.

Comment: @pythonraptor: Oops, thank you and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Both `%f` and `%lf` work for printing `float` and `double` in C99 and later (in C90, only `%f` was defined by the standard).  Use `%Lf` for `long double`.  With `scanf()` (not used in the question), the formats are `%f` for `float`, `%lf` for `double`, and `%Lf` for `long double`.  The reason that `%f` works for printing both `float` and `double` is that default argument promotion rules mean that `float` arguments to `printf()` are automatically converted to `double.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried your suggestion and still cannot get a proper solution. Can you provide some more guidance or your own solution?

Comment: Even with the for loop and tanf vs tan, I still get the same results for both single and double variables.

Comment: @Bathsheba I posted Python code above to demonstrate what I want to achieve in C.

Answer (score 1):

Two main issues here:

First, the `tan` function takes a `double` and returns a `double`.  Use `tanf` instead which takes a `float` and returns a `float`.  So change this:

```
tanangle = tan(angle);
```

To this:

```
tanangle = tanf(angle);
```

Second, the `%f` format specifier by default prints 6 digits of precision.  That's not enough to see the different between single and double precision floating point.  Expand the precision to say 15 digits and you'll see a difference.  So then this:

```
printf("tan(%f) = %f\n", angle, tanangle);
```

Becomes:

```
printf("tan(%.15f) = %.15f\n", angle, tanangle);
```

And this:

```
printf("tan(%lf) = %lf\n", angle2, tanangle2);
```

Becomes:

```
printf("tan(%.15lf) = %.15lf\n", angle2, tanangle2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I see a difference now! 

Two other questions, if I may; In Python, when I store single precision floating points, fewer digits are actually printed than when I print double precision floating points. Why is C different? I also get slightly different results when evaluating the angles in C vs with Python.

Also, to get the last angle to be close to pi/2 in double precision, I have to use pi/2 + pi/20 for the while loop. Why doesn't this happen in single precision?

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the number of digits to change

`printf()` is controlling the number of digits printed, not the type of the variable.

Use `"%e"` to see the floating point nature of a `float` rather than fixed with `"%f"`.
To see all the useful digits, rather than print to the default precision of 6,  use a *precision* modifier.

`xxx_DECIMAL_DIG - 1` is the number of decimal digits to use with `"%e"` to see a total of `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits.   It is the number of digits need to distinguish all of that floating point type. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

```
#include <float.h>

  // printf("tan(%f) = %f\n", angle, tanangle);
  printf("tan(%.*e) = %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, angle, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, tanangle);

  // printf("tan(%f) = %f\n", angle2, tanangle2);
  printf("tan(%.*e) = %.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, angle2, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, tanangle2);
```

---

Code could use `atanf()` to get the `float` result when the result is saved in a `float`.

```
// tanangle = tan(angle);`
tanangle = tanf(angle);`

printf("tan(%.*e) = %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, angle, FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, tanangle);
```

---

Rather than approximate pi with fixed values, let the system calculate the best.

```
//float pi_single = 3.1415926;
//double pi_double = 3.141592653589793;
float pi_single = acosf(-1);
double pi_double = acos(-1);
```

---

Better to use an integer loop

```
for (int i=0; i<= 20; i++) {
  float angle = i*pi_single/20;
  float tanangle = tanf(angle);
  printf("tan(%.*e) = %.*e\n", 
    FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, angle, 
    FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, tanangle);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is it possible to display in regular decimals instead of scientific notation?

Comment: Nice answer but one reservation in the way that you suggest `pi` can be computed. Issue with that is that no standard (not even IEEE754) guarantees that the best result for *pi* for your type will be returned. Far better then to define it yourself or use a maths library. I know this is C++ but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778240/does-c11-14-17-or-20-introduce-a-standard-constant-for-pi/49778493#49778493

Comment: @pythonraptor. "Is it possible to display in regular decimals instead of scientific notation?" --> Sure, use `"*.f"`.  That would provide less information when `x` is small (uninformative leading zeros, truncated digits) or noise when `x` is  large (uninformative least significant digits.)  Try `printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, some_double);` as a compromise.

Comment: @Bathsheba  Should `acos(-1)` not provide the best machine pi, which I agree is not guaranteed as you comment, the quality of the math library is weak and any trig math.h results would have weaknesses/suspect too.  Perhaps as a compromise, , code could specify the pi constant to certainly more digits than than 99.99999% of compilers need today, such as `double pi_d = ‭3.14159265358979323846264338327950288‬; pi_f = ‭3.14159265358979323846264338327950288‬f;`.